# SQL Master Data Services 2016 Excel Publish

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2016, sql-server-2016

I'm testing Master Data Services on SQL 2016 CTP 3.3 (azure VM). I've got a MDS model up and running. I can browse the model in Excel 2016 with the Master Data Services add-in.

If I create a new entity (table), it creates the new table and I can go into SQL server management studio to see the stg.NewTable with the column names I set.

When I add rows, and hit the publish button, I don't see the rows being added to the stage table for me to see in the database. Am I missing something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.. MDS puts many many tables in by default, I wasn't looking in the obscurely named tables at the top. Just need to stop and look at the database structure!

Answer (score 0):

When you load the data in MDS using Excel Add-in, the data is directly loaded into the entity table and not in the staging table. You can either extract the data using subscription view created on your entity or you can get the name of the entity table from mdm.tblEntity table and execute a select query on that table.

Comment: Thanks ! took me awhile but I finally figure this out

Answer (score 0):

When you enter any data from MDS UI it gets stored in the mdm tables in MDM database. To get the data, you need Subscription Views and ETL(SSIS or any other tool)